# Matlab: Optimize this?

Tags: optimization, matlab, vectorization

Im v new to matlab. Have been tasked with speeding up a procedure. Im sure there is a better way to do the following statements:

```
for i = 2:length(WallId)
     if WallId(i) ~= WallId(i-1)
        ReducedWallId = [ReducedWallId;WallId(i)];
        ReducedWallTime = [ReducedWallTime;WallTime(i)];
        GroupCount = [GroupCount;tempCount];
        tempCount = 1;
    else
        tempCount = tempCount +1;
    end
end
```

I can preallocate the various vars to 'length(WallId)' but what do I do with the extra after its done? Do I care?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
idx = find([true diff(WallId) ~= 0]);
ReducedWallId = WallId(idx);
ReducedWallTime = WallTime(idx);
GroupCount = diff([idx numel(WallId)+1]);
```

Assuming what you want is a summary of the unique data in WallId and WallTime, then you should 
make sure that WallId is sorted first. You can re-organise WallTime to match, as follows:

```
[WallId, ind] = sort(WallId);
WallTime = WallTime(ind);
```

Also, you'll only get the right answer if WallTime matches whenever WallId does.

Comment: Can you explain how the 'GroupCount' line works? Im getting a 'horzcat' error there. Makes me think I've copied it wrong.

Comment: I get it now. Is there is a semi-colon missing? Probably cropped out by the website.

Comment: Depends on the orientation of the WallId vector. My version assumes it's a row vector. If it's a column vector, then you will need to add some semi-colons, as suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Use vectorization.

```
ReducedWallId=WallId(find(diff(WallId)~=0));
```

and similarly for ReducedWallTime.

The explicit for-loops are extremely slow. Using vector-operations speeds everything up considerably. This is a general theme in optimizing MATLAB code and is covered in detail in various documents found in the web.

Comment: How would I get the counts then?

Comment: you could use the tabulate() function from the statistics toolbox: y=tabulate(WallId); counts=y(:,2);

Comment: You don't need to use `find`. `ReducedWallId=WallId(diff(WallId)~=0);` will be faster and has the same effect. Look up logical subscripting.